# Using VBA to Select and Highlight Excel Rows

Tags: vba, excel, rows, highlight

How can I tell Excel to highlight rows by their row number.  For instance, let's say I wanted row 6, 10, 150, 201 highlighted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another one based on Mote's `.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex`

This one doesn't restrict you to enter the row numbers but gives the user the flexibility to choose the rows at runtime.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Ret = Application.InputBox("Please select the rows that you would like to color", "Color Rows", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not Ret Is Nothing Then Ret.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> Is there a way to write the macro to read the row numbers from a list and highlight the rows?

Yes there is a way. Let's say the list in Cell A1 to A10 then you can use this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long, sh As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '~~> Set this to the sheet where the rows need to be colored
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")

    '~~> Change Sheet1 to the sheet which has the list
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 1 To 10
            If Not Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) = 0 And _
            IsNumeric(.Range("A" & i).Value) Then _
            sh.Rows(.Range("A" & i).Value).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 '<~~ Red
        Next i
    End With

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, just a quick clarification, I should have included it before.  The spreadsheet has several thousand records (rows).  Is there a way to write the macro to read the row numbers from a list and highlight the rows?  This is a daily report I look at.  I'd like to automated as much as I can.  Then I can filter by color and just see the ones I need.

Comment: Yes you can do that. Updating post.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to Motes' answer,  you can use conditional formatting.

Eg: select A1:J500, Conditional formatting >> New rule >> Use a formula...

For the formula enter: `=OR(ROW()=6, ROW()=10, ROW()=150, ROW()=201)`

Answer (score 4):

For basic VBA code, you can always start recording a macro, perform the action, stop recording, look at what code was generated, and then clean that up to do what you want. For example, recording the action of highlighting a row (setting the value of Interior.Color) gives you:

```
Rows("13:13").Select
Range("C13").Activate
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

The selection commands and extraneous Interior properties can be removed giving you:

```
Rows("13:13").Interior.Color = 65535
```

Adding in the row multi-select:

```
Rows("6:6,10:10,150:150,201:201").Interior.Color = 65535
```

Summary:

- Record macro
- View Excel's version
- Use/Edit what code you need

Comment: + 1 for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 3):

```
objWB.Cells(rowNum,201).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

etc

Comment: Why not just Rows(201).Interior.ColorIndex = 6?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Didn't realize the date on this, but thought I'd add this in since it was relevant to the chosen answer.

In addition to Siddharth Rout's answer, since I don't have enough rep to comment yet, you can dynamically figure out how many rows there are in your worksheet with these two lines.  `xlCellTypeConstants` could be changed to another XlCellType constant that you need, and the range can always be changed to accommodate to your spreadsheet.

```
Dim numRows As Integer
numRows = Range("A2", Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Cells.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it is not as concise or elegant as other answers, but it gets the job done.  When I was writing code for my own application I needed to loop through my code.  Also, instead of highlighting the entire row, I only needed to highlight a portion of the rows.

```
Sub Highlight()
Dim ThisWB As Workbook
Dim ThisWS As Worksheet
Dim rows(0 To 3) As Integer
Dim test As String

Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set ThisWS = ThisWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

rows(0) = 6
rows(1) = 10
rows(2) = 150
rows(3) = 201

For i = 0 To 3
    test = "A" & rows(i) & ":H" & rows(i)
    ThisWS.Range(test).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve the same thing using conditional formatting

- put list of values in a column (I use a separate tab and give the list a name)
- under conditional formatting - New Rule - "use a formula to determine with cells to format"
- read this article http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45670/how-to-highlight-a-row-in-excel-using-conditional-formatting/
- the rule uses vlookup in the formula- =$A2=VLOOKUP($A2,list,1,FALSE)